# How to fix qsort comparator causing segmentation fault

Tags: c

The comparator function I've written for `qsort` causes segmentation fault errors to be thrown every time its run. Specifically the `qsort()` command itself causes the errors, commenting it out makes the code run perfectly fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "sort.h"
#include <sys/stat.h>

int compare(const void *r1, const void *r2) {
  return (strcmp(r1, r2));
}

//Function to compare strings in an array of strings for qsort
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  struct stat fs;
  //exists only to get file size
  stat(argv[1], &fs);
  int file_size = fs.st_size;
  int number_of_records = file_size / 100;
  char AllRecords[file_size][100];
  fread(AllRecords, 100, file_size, file);
  fclose(file);
  int i = sizeof(AllRecords);
  //  int l = compare(AllRecords[0],AllRecords[1]);
  //  Test, current bug, calling qsort causes errors
  qsort(AllRecords, i, 100, compare);
  FILE *file2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
  fwrite(AllRecords, 100, i, file2);
  fclose(file2);
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: And `sizeof(AllRecords)` is?..

Comment: @user58697, `char AllRecords[file_size][100];` is a complete declaration, so `sizeof(AllRecords)` should be `100` times the value of `file_size`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be very much more careful with the sizes you use.  This code works, fixing a variety of issues with the size of the arrays.  Note that there is a limit to how big an array you can create on the stack.  On Unix systems, 1 MiB has ample margin for error (the limit is normally 8 MiB); on Windows, the limit is normally 1 MiB so the limit imposed here is probably a little to large — maybe `(1000 * 1000)` would be safe; maybe a smaller value would be better, such as `(1024 * 1024 * 15 / 16)`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_FILE_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

static int compare(const void  *r1, const void *r2)
{
    return(strcmp(r1, r2));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert(argc == 3);
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    struct stat fs;
    stat(argv[1], &fs);
    int file_size = fs.st_size;
    if (file_size > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "file %s is too big to be sorted by this program\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int number_of_records = file_size / 100;
    char AllRecords[number_of_records][100];
    fread(AllRecords, 100, file_size, file);
    fclose(file);
    qsort(AllRecords, number_of_records, 100, compare);
    FILE *file2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    fwrite(AllRecords, 100, number_of_records, file2);
    fclose(file2);
    return(0);
}
```

One of the problems is then generating sample data.  I used a random data generator to generate 99 character 'lines' terminated by null bytes (so that the string comparison would have null terminated strings.

Input:

```
LLWNMGWMIQECKYLWFFIHWSZVYBQLLYTDAXNQNCQRBJZMZNFMMNCBAFYIIXUKXEBGSQHIYVCDVWCUHLXLOCOETLRPZRSGWDERQAZ
YNWEULRIMNODDAKABCKVAXTWLMPFOFIGRIJLKPVTWCFJGXAZEWKZFWCIZVQZYPADMBQOOHITVPEVWOIUSZISJOQTHQHCXEADIHW
YSHUYAQTPVTBKKHXQQXZMJIQVJRFJSNZSXKMHNJRAPNYWVSJRIHVHUBJJJAMRVBJZWWEACTUXLDXEFIDALHJBOKXJBAQJFABKLR
UWXIJELISTPAFXSKEGQHHJYPKWGLBXJSQWFHCAPRJTLQHRZEEEJAELOMKDAQIDIBZKZMCYNCMVLTXDUKLYGEIBVXTXNKPOUGMQE
NFUVXYBDQYMIEVWEQUYPTEASNSOQHZRLLLKXSBSQJFJBNRLSPUELCYTWDLLMTQKKHWFVFCQXNEBBMAPASRZSIOELSZGGFDDWJSK
OXQGGDODECBRVSXUAMZSLIHUJRAUFGMMORRBBGHECQLRWSVZGZWTSSBJVPTTRUIDJVGKTFGJFMSOHHTBIAEFIMUSYXMJAIRIZTU
XRRQOOBLDYLQQMKVFSOIZNTXAARKUZRBFCAEJDGCZGXHUTWHHOHERWPKOLDBCEHCUXPHVJMEUEJVTUDCQFXWAEWMPZPROKSOKAE
LURFJLTYKIIWTMWJLXZGOGCPMMRWZEOCSODVRSQDFTMJJILCIZNQWITWFJSCSAZTTJBYEGAWXBAYGQVQOMQTKTEHGUTOOMOCFAZ
NGBPRHOEICRLXPVTMHULNYJNNRJYVZDDGHDFHJFKELHUGGYWHSMBPCRTAAVHOKAITDPTPGWOOMSHHGLRNVQBMTHCFCPQGDRTCAV
ZJRHMYEPSWTRPGNFZMGPHOSFAFADGTDMISIWGSOCLSYGBURDJEKYYYLZXHHXIYYUVTYNXYBKJLSPNVXIKDZNSIZDITIOWGODJNL
```

Converted using `tr '\0' '\n'` (or vice versa to convert newlines to null bytes).

Output:

```
LLWNMGWMIQECKYLWFFIHWSZVYBQLLYTDAXNQNCQRBJZMZNFMMNCBAFYIIXUKXEBGSQHIYVCDVWCUHLXLOCOETLRPZRSGWDERQAZ
LURFJLTYKIIWTMWJLXZGOGCPMMRWZEOCSODVRSQDFTMJJILCIZNQWITWFJSCSAZTTJBYEGAWXBAYGQVQOMQTKTEHGUTOOMOCFAZ
NFUVXYBDQYMIEVWEQUYPTEASNSOQHZRLLLKXSBSQJFJBNRLSPUELCYTWDLLMTQKKHWFVFCQXNEBBMAPASRZSIOELSZGGFDDWJSK
NGBPRHOEICRLXPVTMHULNYJNNRJYVZDDGHDFHJFKELHUGGYWHSMBPCRTAAVHOKAITDPTPGWOOMSHHGLRNVQBMTHCFCPQGDRTCAV
OXQGGDODECBRVSXUAMZSLIHUJRAUFGMMORRBBGHECQLRWSVZGZWTSSBJVPTTRUIDJVGKTFGJFMSOHHTBIAEFIMUSYXMJAIRIZTU
UWXIJELISTPAFXSKEGQHHJYPKWGLBXJSQWFHCAPRJTLQHRZEEEJAELOMKDAQIDIBZKZMCYNCMVLTXDUKLYGEIBVXTXNKPOUGMQE
XRRQOOBLDYLQQMKVFSOIZNTXAARKUZRBFCAEJDGCZGXHUTWHHOHERWPKOLDBCEHCUXPHVJMEUEJVTUDCQFXWAEWMPZPROKSOKAE
YNWEULRIMNODDAKABCKVAXTWLMPFOFIGRIJLKPVTWCFJGXAZEWKZFWCIZVQZYPADMBQOOHITVPEVWOIUSZISJOQTHQHCXEADIHW
YSHUYAQTPVTBKKHXQQXZMJIQVJRFJSNZSXKMHNJRAPNYWVSJRIHVHUBJJJAMRVBJZWWEACTUXLDXEFIDALHJBOKXJBAQJFABKLR
ZJRHMYEPSWTRPGNFZMGPHOSFAFADGTDMISIWGSOCLSYGBURDJEKYYYLZXHHXIYYUVTYNXYBKJLSPNVXIKDZNSIZDITIOWGODJNL
```

Of course, with this data, the string comparisons would not need to find a null byte, but if there were repeated lines in the file, then it would be crucial.

Comment: Isn't the `strncmp(..., ...., 100)` is more appropriate? `AllRecords[file_size][100];` should be `AllRecords[number_of_records][100];`.

Comment: I suppose you could use `strncmp()` — it would also work — though the question used `strcmp()` so presumably the data is null-terminated.  That might be too big of an assumption, I suppose.  But the key point is that the comparator is passed 'pointers to pointers' so you have to dereference the values once.

Comment: I updated the question with your correct comment about array size.  I also put a size check on the file to ensure that the stack isn't blown on Unix (where the size is typically 8 MiB) — it probably allows files that are a little too large for comfort on Windows (where the stack size is typically 1 MiB).  The code should use `malloc()` and `free()` instead for large files.

Comment: Pedantically, you are right about what `compare` actually receives. However, the original version of `compare` is also perfectly correct. All you do in your version is introduce an extra number of intermediate conversions on the path from `void *` to `char *` inside `compare`. Why? They are not really necessary. The reason of the crash is in the wrong sizes passed to `qsort`.

Comment: @AnT: Hmmm — yes, you're correct. At one point, I got a crash with the original comparator function, but I now have no record of what else was wrong with that variant of the code.  Empirically, you are correct.  Another edit coming up.

Answer (score 0):

The `qsort` function requires two numeric parameters: `nitems` and `size`. The first is the number of items. I think you have this stored in `number_of_records`. The second is the size of a single record, which you are using a literal `100`.

Instead of passing `i`, which is the total size in bytes of the entire array, try passing `number_of_records`:

```
qsort(AllRecords, number_of_records, 100, compare);
```

Comment: Switching to number_of_records fixed the segmentation fault, thanks for spotting that! I'm getting weird behavior as far as how its getting sorted. The first 4 bytes are supposed to be a key that I can sort by, so I thought that by running strcmp it would find the most significant bit where they differ, so the higher value for the key would be sorted to the top, but I'm getting a more or less random distribution of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Fix various problems at once.

`file_size` is not the number of records expected in `file`, `number_of_records` is the expected number of records.

`i` should not be the byte size of `AllRecords`, nor the count of elements in `AllRecords[]`, but the count of items successfully read from `fread()`.

```
//char AllRecords[file_size][100];
//fread(AllRecords, 100, file_size, file);
//int i = sizeof(AllRecords);

char AllRecords[number_of_records][100];
int i = fread(AllRecords, 100, number_of_records, file);`

qsort(AllRecords, i, 100, compare); // This is OK
```

Hopefully `number_of_records == i`, but crap happens when reading files.  The return value from `fread()` is the best indicator.